# Problemas con evento blur

Tags: php, jquery

Buenas tardes compañeros,

Recurro nuevamente a su ayuda. Tal vez sea algo tonto, pero no le he dado con el chiste.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<input type="text" id="documento" name="documento">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#documento').on('blur', function(){
        var numero_documento = $('#documento').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "inventario_validar_documento.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {numberID:numero_documento,id:2},
            success: function(datas) {
                if (datas.validar==1){
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'info',
                        title: 'INFORMACIÓN',
                        html: 
                        'El documento No. <b>'+numero_documento+'</b> ya se encuentra registrado con los siguientes datos:<br>Número de movimiento: <b>'+datas.movimiento+'</b> <br>Fecha: <b>'+datas.fecha+'</b> <br>Cliente: <b>'+datas.cliente+'</b> <br>Bodega: <b>'+datas.bodega+'</b>',
                        showConfirmButton: true
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                            $('#documento').focus();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

El problema radica que efectivamente me ejecuta pero de forma automática pierde el foco generando el mensaje y hay veces que se ejecuta muchísimas veces... como si cayera en un ciclo. Me toca cambiar de pestaña y volver a el para que se detenga o darle click en cualquier parte del documento.

Alguien de pronto sabe que puede estar generando este problema?

De antemano, muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan prestar

Comment: ¿Consideraste la propagación del evento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la ejecución en ciclo sucede por la forma en que haces la validación...

- Capturas el `value` del `input` cuando pierde el foco
- Realizas la petición vía `ajax`
- Si el documento ya existe, muestras una notificación con `sweet alert`
- Enfocas el `input` nuevamente
- Al hacer click en el botón de `sweet alert`, el `input` pierde el foco
- Por ende se ejecuta de nuevo la validación

Creo que podrías vaciar el `input` tras la validación y agregar una comprobación en el evento `blur`... *Me genera duda el evento `focus`. Si deseas, prueba sin el*

```
<input type="text" id="documento" name="documento">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#documento').on('blur', function(){
    var numero_documento = $('#documento').val();
    //Validamos que la variable no esté vacía
    if (numero_documento != ''){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inventario_validar_documento.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {numberID:numero_documento,id:2},
        success: function(datas) {
          if (datas.validar==1){
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'info',
              title: 'INFORMACIÓN',
              html: 
              'El documento No. <b>'+numero_documento+'</b> ya se encuentra registrado con los siguientes datos:<br>Número de movimiento: <b>'+datas.movimiento+'</b> <br>Fecha: <b>'+datas.fecha+'</b> <br>Cliente: <b>'+datas.cliente+'</b> <br>Bodega: <b>'+datas.bodega+'</b>',
              showConfirmButton: true
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.value) {
                //Vaciamos el contenido del campo y luego enfocamos el input
                $('#documento').val('').focus();
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañeros por la ayuda ofrecida. Efectivamente el problema era en la propagación del blur.